# C# EMGU CV considers an imagefile different from itself

Tags: c#, emgucv

So I have been experimenting with EMGU and I ran into the following problem:
I have created a a little application which displays a message box if the images are the same or if they differ.
Here is my code:

```
using Emgu.CV;
using Emgu.CV.UI;
using Emgu.Util;
using Emgu.CV.Structure;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Image<Bgr,byte> img1 = new Image<Bgr, byte>("S:\\Users\\XYZ\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2015\\Projects\\EMGUCV TEST\\Testimg\\raven1.png");
  Image<Bgr,byte> img2 = new Image<Bgr, byte>("S:\\Users\\XYZ\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2015\\Projects\\EMGUCV TEST\\Testimg\\raven1.png");

 if(img1==img2)
 {
    MessageBox.Show("The images are the same you bozo!");
 }
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("The images differ..dummy!");
}
```

}

The problem:
Even if the same file is inserted into both image variables (as in the example above), the comparison will say that they do not match.
When I apply AbsDif or CMP functions they do not show any difference in the image.

Has anyone ran into this before? If so, please tell me, what am I missing here?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `Image` will use reference equality.  Those references aren't equal.  Load them as arrays of bytes and check that the arrays are equal instead.

Answer (score 0):

You're not making the comparison you think you are. You have two separate references - and you're testing for reference equality. If you want to actually check that every pixel is identical you want to do:

```
if (img1.Equals(img2))
{
    ...
}
else
{
    ...
}
```

Source: http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/2.0.0.0/html/cb458162-4427-757f-c468-7e759bc7f916.htm

Comment: I don't think this will work.  `Image` uses the inherited implementation of `Object.Equals(object)`.

Comment: The documentation says otherwise. http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/2.0.0.0/html/cb458162-4427-757f-c468-7e759bc7f916.htm

Comment: Ah, my bad!  I thought it was the `Image` from `System.Drawing`, and forgot this is emgu.